Powershell ListView with GridView isnt updating properly
I want to remove one item from a ListView with GridView. After i removed the item from the GridView and reloading the GUI it still there.
<ListView Name="ListView_Panel" Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Path ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding pathid}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="file date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding filedate}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="device" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding device}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="mean frequenzy [Hz]" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding meanfreq}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="data length" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding datalength}"/>
    </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Open NetCDF" Name="menuOption1"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Set Zoom" Name="menuOption2"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Name="menuExit"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>

This is my XML Part and here is how iam loading it:
$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$sync.Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

#Importieren der Objekte
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        Write-Output "Adding $($_.Name)"
        $sync.Add($_.Name, $sync.Window.FindName($_.Name))
    }
    catch {
        throw
    }
}

I want to remove the path id from the GridView. I tried to delete the GridViewColumn line and reloaded the gui but its still there and i dont understand why. I tried restarting my vscode my pc cause i was thinking there is a cache or something but i cant figure it out. Renaming the Listview worked but that isnt a thing for me.
Maybe someone knows.

I'm entirely unable to reproduce the behavior described. If I remove the Path ID gridview column from the XAML document, the GUI reflects it as expected. Perhaps you could post the complete code snippet with which you're seeing this behavior?

Okay after removing line by line i figured it out... I have a languagefile where i set the header for the selected language:
$sync.ListView_Panel.View.Columns[0].Header = "Path ID"

That makes a lot more sense, glad to hear you figured it out :)
